# Word Macro for turning a number sequence into a number range (example: 1, 2, 3 into 1-3)

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I am producing an author and subject index for a professor's book. I have already created the index using MS Word. But now I have a series of consecutive numbers for each subject/author that needs to be turned into an actual sequence.

So for example:

```
Agency (human and divine), 113, 114, 115, 339
```

needs to become

```
Agency (human and divine), 113–115, 339
```

The VBA code I'm currently using is a modification of [code found here](http://tyndaletech.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/indexing-semi-automatically.html). The problem with that original code is that it missed doublets like 98–99. Instead, the author sent me the revised code below. The problem with this revised code is that, when it gets to the end of my index, it just keeps going and going and... It can't stop and so Word ends up freezing and then I need to force close it.

So, my question: can the following code be edited so that it stops when it hits the end of the document? If so, how? Thanks!

```
Sub RemoveSurplus()
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
   On Error GoTo SubEnd   'remove after debug
Do While Errornumber = 0
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    R1 = Selection
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    R2 = Selection
    If (R1 = "-" And R2 = "-") Then
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    End If
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=False

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]@, [0-9]@"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    N1 = Selection + 1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    N2 = Selection + 1
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    If (N2 = N1 + 1) Then
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.TypeText Text:="-"
    Else: Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    End If
 Loop
SubEnd:
End Sub
```

Comment: `Errornumber` is always going to be 0.  It isn't defined anywhere and its value isn't changed in the loop, so your only exit condition for the loop is if it throws an error.  Note that the rest of the code doesn't appear to work either when I test it.

Comment: So how should I set a different exit condition? I tried getting it to exit when it reached a character I set (like ~) but that didn't work.

Comment: For now I'm just using F8 to run the script one step at a time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, the following code will do the job thanks to some help from [Vipul Gajjar](https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/~01a2b3221217d0c331).

```
Sub RemoveSurplus()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = falsee
    Application.StatusBar = True

    Dim totChar As Long

    KillEndBlanks

    totChar = ActiveDocument.Content.End - 13

    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
   On Error GoTo SubEnd   'remove after debug
Do While Errornumber = 0
    Application.StatusBar = "Please Wait: Line#[" & Selection.End & "] out of Lines#[" & ActiveDocument.Content.End & "] is in progress....!!!!"
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    R1 = Selection
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    R2 = Selection
    If (R1 = "-" And R2 = "-") Then
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    End If
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=False

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]@, [0-9]@"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    N1 = Selection + 1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    N2 = Selection + 1
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    If (N2 = N1 + 1) Then
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.TypeText Text:="-"
    Else: Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    End If

    If Selection.End = endV And count1 < 100 Then
        endV = Selection.End
        count1 = count1 + 1
    ElseIf endV = Selection.End And count1 >= 100 Then
        GoTo SubEnd
    Else
        count1 = 0
        endV = Selection.End
    End If
 Loop
SubEnd:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub

Sub KillEndBlanks()
'
' KillEndBlanks Macro
'
    ' Go to the end of the file
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    ' Select the last character
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    ' As long as the last character is a carriage return [CHR(13)]...
    While Selection.Text = vbCr
        ' ... Delete the character, and select the new last character
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Wend
    ' Go to the end of the file again to not leave a character selected
    Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
    While Selection.Text = Chr(13) Or Selection.Text = Chr(32)
        ' ... Delete the character, and select the new last character
        Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Wend
    Selection.Range.Text = Trim(Selection.Range.Text)
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
End Sub
```